# ActiveAdmin: Hide a whole panel in a smart way

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

In order to only show relevant information to my users I want to disable the whole panel when all fields inside that panel are empty.

Currently I do this hacky method to get to this result:

```
if resource.phone.present? or
    resource.fax.present? or 
    resource.email.present? or 
    resource.website.present?
  panel I18n.t('contact_details') do
    attributes_table_for resource do
      row :phone if resource.phone.present?
      row :fax if resource.fax.present?
      row :email if resource.email.present?
      row :website if resource.website.present?
    end
  end
end
```

So I need to check all fields in order to know if I display the panel.
Then once I display the panel I need to check all the fields again in order to display the given row or not.

Now the user sees only what is relevant but my admin code is cluttered and no longer as maintainable.

Comment: I don't get it, the first `if` checks if you have *all* the elements present, why do you test again in the `attributes_table_for` block?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first post, though some more context would be nice IMO, it might be worth checking if changes to other parts of the code / data model would make this part easier (apart from what @tokland already said).

Comment: @tokland: you're right, these have to be `or`s rather than `and`s. I changed that

Answer (score 3):

I don't know ActiveAdmin, so I can only offer a local improvement.  That said, a little metaprogramming could work here.  The idea is to have the list of resource items in one place:

```
RESOURCES_ITEMS = [
  :phone,
  :fax,  
  :email,   
  :resource,
]
```

and then use that list with [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) and [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
if RESOURCE_ITEMS.any? { |item| resource.public_send(item).present? }
  panel I18n.t('contact_details') do
    attributes_table_for resource do
      RESOURCE_ITEMS.each do |item|
        if resource.public_send(item).present?
          row.public_send(item)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

While not a huge improvement, this does DRY the list of resource items.